# Leave out function parts refering to non-existing columns

Tags: r, function, error-handling

I have a big dataframe of about 500k rows and a few thousand columns. Further, I was given a huge function with about 7 thousand lines code that processes this data in order to make it more handy (setting dates, defining factor levels, and so on). Let's call it `huge_fun`. It looks like this:

```
 huge_fun <- function(data){
   data$a1 <- factor(data$a1, levels= letters)
   # .....
   data$j1 <- as.Date(data$j1, origin = "1899-12-30")
   # ....
   data$z1 <- factor(data$z1, levels= LETTERS)
   # .....
   data$z174920 <- as.Date(data$z174920, "%m/%d/%y")
   # .....

   return(data)
 }
```

I do not need all the columns for my analysis and in order to save ram I load only the needed columns. The problem is that applying the `huge_fun` to my data returns an error because inside the function columns are selected that I did not load. It looks like this:

```
 df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, 10*10), ncol= 10)), paste0(letters[1:10], "1"))
 huge_fun(df)
 # Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "z1", value = integer(0)) : 
 # replacement has 0 rows, data has 10
```

What I've tried is to use `data.table` rather than an `data.frame` object and indeed the error does not occur anymore:

```
 dt <- setNames(data.table::data.table(matrix(rep(NA, 10*10), ncol= 10)), paste0(letters[1:10], "1"))
 huge_fun(dt)
```

This works but the problem here is that the `huge_fun` function actually adds those columns I did not load before! Hence, my data becomes massively big and even after hours the function is still running. How can I leave out the function parts that process columns that I did not load? Or refering to both methods above: How can we avoid the error in the `data.frame` method or how can we avoid the function adding new columns in the `data.table` method? Again, the function has about 7k lines of code and the columns I need differ depending on the analysis, hence, I can't edit the function by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fix, you could create an S3 class and define a method for `$<-`:

```
DF <- iris
foo <- function(DF) {
  DF$b <- DF$a * 2
  DF
}

foo(DF)
#Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, b, value = numeric(0)) :
#  replacement has 0 rows, data has 150

class(DF) <- c("special_DF", class(DF))

`$<-.special_DF` <- function (x, name, value) {
  if (is.null(value) || length(value) == 0L) {
    warning("skipping zero-length assignment")
    return(x)
    }
  `$<-.data.frame`(x, name, value)
}
foo(DF)
#works
```

You might also need to create methods for `[<-` and `[[<-`.

However, ultimately, that horrible function needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Awesome! That wors as expected! I am afraid I won't have the time to adapt the 7k lines code to every analysis we are running. So your post here helped me a alot!

Comment: You don’t need to adapt it each time if you use if conditions and parameters to make parts of the function optional.